# GitHub actions does not get triggered on commits or PRs created by github-actions (bot)

Tags: github, github-actions

I have set up GitHub actions for the repository [here](https://github.com/SpoonLabs/sorald) and [`tests.yml`](https://github.com/SpoonLabs/sorald/blob/master/.github/workflows/tests.yml) gets triggered on `push` to `master` and if a pull request is created. However, when a pull request is created by `github-actions (bot)`, the CI is not triggered. See pull requests by the bot [here](https://github.com/SpoonLabs/sorald/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc%20author%3Aapp%2Fgithub-actions). Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question and the short answer is this was a deliberate design decision.  I came across [this discussion](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/issues/48) and [related documentation](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/blob/main/docs/concepts-guidelines.md#triggering-further-workflow-runs) which describes several workarounds.